# Laravel route not defined error when it is clearly defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to handle a basic form with laravel and am running in to an issue where my POST route isn't being detected and is resulting in a route not defined error in the blade template. My goal is to resolve this error and post the form to the controller, then access the various form fields with the $request param.

This is the error: `Route [become-a-customer] not defined.`

I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('become-a-customer') }}" method="post" class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input name="last_name" type="email" class="form-control" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token " value="{{ Session::token() }}"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/become-a-customer', 'BecomeACustomerFormController@postBecomeACustomer');
```

**BecomeACustomerController . php**

```
class BecomeACustomerFormController extends Controller
{
    public function postBecomeACustomer(Request $request)
    {
        $firstName = $request['first_name'];
        $lastName = $request['last_name'];
        ...
        ...
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```php
Route::post('/become-a-customer', 'BecomeACustomerFormController@postBecomeACustomer')->name('become-a-customer');
```

Answer (score 10):

use this command

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 2):

In Your blade Template, You have used the **Named route** for the form action but, it is not specified in the route file (Web.php).

Change your route file like this

```
Route::post('/become-a-customer', 'BecomeACustomerFormController@postBecomeACustomer')->name('become-a-customer');
```

OR, you have to change the form action like this

```
action="{{ url('become-a-customer') }}"
```

Using the named route is the best practice for a Laravel project.

Answer (score 1):

you can also define as following where "as" key is for naming your route

```
Route::post('/become-a-customer',  ['uses' => 'BecomeACustomerFormController@postBecomeACustomer', 'as' => 'become-a-customer']);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me `url('routeName')` worked instead of `route('routeName')`

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache or Nginx configurations. Sometimes a redirect from https to http will alter the method from POST to GET.

I'd recommend setting up a temporary endpoint for GET by the same Route and placing a `dd()` statement in it to test the theory.

Answer (score 0):

`route()` method uses route name which is undefined. You can define it via `name()` method on route as below

```
Route::post('/become-a-customer', 'BecomeACustomerFormController@postBecomeACustomer')->name('become-a-customer');
```

for more see [doucmentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes)